# pre-load nested resource with condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my simple attendance app, there are `:students`, `:semesters`, `:attendances`. Attendance has columns `student:references semester:references date:date present:boolean`.

semester.rb

```
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :semesters
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances
end
```

attendance.rb

```
class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :semester
  belongs_to :student
  validates_presence_of :date
end
```

In the `semesters#show` page, I want to display each student in that semester, and each student's attendance percentage like below.

[image: attendance]

It works, but I have to filter through some `:attendances` that aren't associated with the semester before I start count. So my goal is to eager-load the semester, its students, and their attendances that only belong_to that semester.

This way, when I use

```
@semester.students.each do |student|
  student.attendances
end
```

The `.attendances` method should only return those associated with that semester. Is this possible?

Here's what I got

```
# semesters_controller.rb
def show
  @semester = Semester.includes(students: [:attendances])
                      .order('students.first_name')
                      .find params[:id]
end
```

```
# students_helper.rb
def student_attendance(student)
  total = student.attendances.select { |x| x.semester_id == @semester.id }
  present = total.select &:present
  percent = (present.size/total.size.to_f * 100).round rescue 0
  link_to student, class: 'attendance', style: "width: #{percent}%" do
    <<-HTML.html_safe
      <span>#{student.first_name}</span>
      <span>#{percent}%</span>
    HTML
  end
end
```

I've found that using `select {|x| x.semester_id == @semester.id }` instead of `where semester_id: @semester.id` and `select &:present` instead of `where present: true` reduces the number of queries.

Anyways, is there a way that I can load the `:attendances` so that I don't have to go through that first filter (`select {|x| x.semester_id == @semester.id }`)? If I don't filter like I am doing, then it will show that student's attendance percentage for ALL semesters they've ever been in, instead of just this one semester we're trying to show on the #show page.

I just don't want to be loading all that unnecessary data, nah mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already have a way of connecting an attendance directly with a semester (as `belongs_to :semester` is stated in your Attendance class).

Have you tried:

```
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :attendences
end
attendences = @semester.attendences
```

OR just:

```
attendences = Attendence.where(semester: params[:id])
```

(you can use appropriate joins/includes to reduce sql-queries)